# POST (not GET) wikidata query

Tags: ruby, sparql, wikidata

I'm following [these instructions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikidata_Query_Service/User_Manual) to submit a SPARQL query, preferring the POST method as queries may be quite long. But it seems to fail even though the GET works - any way to make a POST query work?

```
sparql = <<END
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel 
WHERE 
{
    ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q146.
    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
END

# Fails with 405 Not writable
resp = Excon.post('https://query.wikidata.org/sparql', body: "query=#{URI::encode(sparql)}")
puts resp.status, resp.body

# Works with 200
resp = Excon.get("https://query.wikidata.org/sparql?query=#{URI::encode(sparql)}")
puts resp.status, resp.body
```

I've tried sending `"Content-Type" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` too, but no luck.

Comment: maybe not helpful and I'm not familiar with Ruby, but my `curl` request works as expected: `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H "Accept: text/html" -d 'format=application/json&query=SELECT ?item ?itemLabel WHERE {?item wdt:P31 wd:Q146. SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }}' https://query.wikidata.org/sparql`

Comment: `Excon.post('https://query.wikidata.org/sparql',
 :body => sparql,
 :headers => { "Content-Type" => "application/sparql-query", 
  "User-Agent" => "Ruby 2.6.4"
 })` or `Excon.post('https://query.wikidata.org/sparql', :body => "query=#{URI::encode(sparql)}",
:headers => { "Content-Type" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "User-Agent" => "Ruby 2.6.4" })`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to the commenters above for showing working examples. I did some further checks based on all obvious combinations, as below.

In summary:

- Use GET if it's short and likely to be reused (since GET queries are cached)
- Ensure you send a `user-agent` header and note that some libraries won't include one by default (otherwise it returns an unexplained 403)
- For POST, best and simplest (in my opinion) is to send a SPARQL query as the entire body with "content-type" as "application/sparql-query", no encoding of the query is necessary here. You can alternatively use the form syntax with "content-type" as "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" and ensure the query is encoded.

```rb
require 'excon'

# any arbitrary query   
sparql = 'SELECT ?item ?itemLabel WHERE { ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q146.  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". } }'

# SUCCESS!
resp = Excon.get("https://query.wikidata.org/sparql?query=#{URI::encode(sparql)}")
puts "GET", resp.status, resp.body[0,100], "\n"

# FAIL! 403 (need user agent)
headers = { "Content-Type" => "application/sparql-query" }
resp= Excon.post('https://query.wikidata.org/sparql', body: sparql, headers: headers)
puts "POST sparql-query", resp.status, resp.body[0,100], "\n"

# SUCCESS!
headers = { "Content-Type" => "application/sparql-query", "User-Agent" => "Ruby 2.6.4" }
resp= Excon.post('https://query.wikidata.org/sparql', body: sparql, headers: headers)
puts "POST sparql-query with user-agent", resp.status, resp.body[0,100], "\n"

# FAIL! 403 (need user agent)
headers = { "Content-Type" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" }
resp = Excon.post('https://query.wikidata.org/sparql', body: "query=#{URI::encode(sparql)}", headers: headers)
puts "POST form", resp.status, resp.body[0,100], "\n"

# SUCCESS!
headers = { "Content-Type" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "User-Agent" => "Ruby 2.6.4" }
resp = Excon.post('https://query.wikidata.org/sparql', body: "query=#{URI::encode(sparql)}", headers: headers)
puts "POST form with user-agent", resp.status, resp.body[0,100], "\n"

# FAIL! 405 (need encoding)
resp = Excon.post('https://query.wikidata.org/sparql', body: "query=#{URI::encode(sparql)}")
puts "POST plain", resp.status, resp.body[0,100], "\n"

# FAIL! 405 (need encoding)
headers = { "User-Agent" => "Ruby 2.6.4" }
resp = Excon.post('https://query.wikidata.org/sparql', body: "query=#{URI::encode(sparql)}", headers: headers)
puts "POST plain with user-agent", resp.status, resp.body[0,100], "\n"
```

**More info**

- [SPARQL 1.1 Protocol](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-protocol/#query-operation)
- [Phabricator issue](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T112151)
- [Wikimedia User-Agent policy](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/User-Agent_policy)